# Angular-ui bootstrap & bootstrap.js

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm quite new to angularjs, and going to use angular + bootstrap in the project, so I was thinking the steps should be like this

`1. import angular.js`
`2. import bootstrap.js`
`3. import bootstrap.css`

However I found there is an `angular-ui bootstrap module` in angular, so I tested to create a dropdown menu in both way, they all work very well, I guess angular-ui should be the recommended way, but **`why shall I use angular-ui bootstrap rather than import bootstrap.js directly?`**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using directly `bootstrap.js` is **NOT** recommended. You will have to do all the data binding manually, by using custom directives plus the bloat to have to include `bootstrap.js` since the `angular-ui.js` library is even more compact than its original since it was rebuild from scratch. You can even stop including `jquery.js` if using `angular-ui.js`

Comment: `bootstrap.js` uses raw jQuery, which doesn't play well with Angular. Don't use them together.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to achieve can be done through the [angular ui-bootstrap module](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), you should use that instead of the twitter-bootstrap-js library.

angular-ui bootstrap has all of the bootstrap-js components, but they have been written from scratch as angular directives. (But they do use Twitter-bootstrap **CSS**)

The alternative would be to use Twitter-bootstrap JS components, and then create your own angular directives that wrap them... which is a bit of unnecessary hassle.

So:

> 1. import bootstrap.css
> 2. import angular.js
> 3. import angular-ui-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Angular-UI is a bridge between the bootstrap javascript components and AngularJS. This means that most of the bootstrap components are wrapped in AngularJS directives for convenience.

This means that you can use the binding of AngularJS when using bootstrap components, for example:

```
<div collapse="isCollapsed">      
    <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>      
</div>
```

Instead of

```
$('#myCollapsible').collapse({
  toggle: false
})
```

Comment: Can I understand like this: angular-ui has defined boostrap into its directives, so that if I want achieve some effects, I just simply to `invoke` those directives functions?

Comment: In AngularJS you don't invoke functions on directives directly. You can place directives in your html (like above the collapse directive) and you can pass information to that directive (like above when passing the isCollapsed boolean to set if the bootstrap component is collapsed or not). Angular-UI prevents that you have to use jQuery to manipulate the bootstrap components, what is essential in AngularJS.